# Search in python using google API

Tags: python, google-api

I want to write a search in python using google api. There is an input and a search button. After clicking the button, I need to receive data from my input and connect my search file and see my input data in Google (google.com needs to open with data from input). How can I do that?

search file:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey="mykey")

  res = service.cse().list(
      q='lectures',
      cx='017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve',
    ).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: The code you posted is using the Custom Search API, but your description ("google.com needs to open") sounds like you actually want to open a web browser. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MattZimmerman yes

Comment: @MattZimmerman can you please help me in this question?

Comment: Try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html